# Reset state of continuous blocks (e.g., transfer function) in Simulink

Tags: simulink, transfer-function

How I can reset the state of a transfer function block in Simulink (i.e., reset back to the initial conditions)?

For example, in an electrical network, this would correspond to reset capacitors/inductors to zero (or an initial state), for example through switches.

I tried using an "Enabled Subsystem" and placing the Transfer Fcn block there but it seems that the state is not reset when Enable changes ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default an enabled subsystem *holds* the states from one enable to the next.  However they may be *reset* by opening the `Enable` Block within the subsystem, and changing the *States when enabling* property to *reset*.

If you need to reset the states during an enable (rather than at the start of it) then you will need to construct your transfer function using individual integrator blocks (and gains; and summation, etc) and use their reset functionality.